# Can someone present an example of linear ordering less trivial than $A = [1,2,3,4,5,6...]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

A linear ordering (loset) is a poset that also satisfies the *trichotomy law*.

> For any $x,y \in A$, we have $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$

A common example is presented as $A = [1,2,3,4,5,6...]$

Can someone present an example that is less trivial than the set presented above so I can see the full utility of linear ordering?

Comment: Try the reals with the usual ordering.

Comment: Or lexicographical ordering of permutations.

Comment: The dictionary ordering. Words $w=(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_N)$, where $w_n \in \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,…,X,Y,Z\}$, are linearly ordered by defining $v \le w$ if and only if the following holds: for each $n$, if $v_i=w_i$ for $1 \le i < n$ and if $v_n \ne w_n$ then $v_n \le w_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples include:

- The set $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers with the usual ordering, which is interesting in that it has the same cardinality as your $A$ but a very different kind of order (a [dense order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order)).
- The [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), which is interesting in that it has the same cardinality as the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers but a substantially different kind of order than the standard order on $\mathbb R$, leading to a different topology than the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.
- The [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) $\omega_1$ (which is used in defining the long line above).